# Junit with .Net Technologies

Tags: asp.net, .net, testing, junit

Is it possible for us to integrate the junit test cases for an application for which we are developing using the ASP.Net Platform?
Since I am from Java j2ee Tech background, have a very less knowledge on .Net Technology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NUnit: http://www.nunit.org/

Comment: So that means we cant use Junit and instead we can use Nunit?

Comment: Yes, I was a bit cryptic about that. Sorry. :)
If you want to test your .net code you must use a .net unit test library. NUnit is very similar to JUnit so it should be the best solution for you.